# Akka Cluster custom serializer:

Tags: serialization, akka, akka-cluster

I am using Akka Cluster to achieve some redundancy and remove single points of failure in my java application. However, I am having some problems with the serialization of the messages when sending them from one machine to another.

I am sending a java object that **doesn't** implement `Serializable`. Because of that, I need to use my own serializer and luckily the object provides a serialization method using Kryo. So, following this [guide](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.4/java/serialization.html) I have created my own akka serializer extending `JSerializer`:

```
import akka.serialization.JSerializer;

public class MyObjectClusterSerializer extends JSerializer {

    public int identifier() {
        return 66666;
    }

    public boolean includeManifest() {
        return false;
    }

    public byte[] toBinary(Object obj) {
        MyObject myObject = (MyObject) obj;
        byte[] bytes = null;
        try {
            bytes = MyObjectHelper.serialize(myObject);
        } catch (SerializationException e) {

        }
        return bytes;
    }

    @Override
    public Object fromBinaryJava(byte[] arg0, Class<?> arg1) {
        MyObject myObject = null;
        try {
            myObject = MyObjectHelper.deserialize(arg0);
        } catch (DeserializationException e) {
        }
        return myObject;
    }

}
```

The code is pretty straightforward and I don't believe that is the problem. Then I add the serializer and the serializer binding to my configuration:

```
serializers {
  myobject = "com.my.awesome.project.MyObjectClusterSerializer"
}

serialization-bindings {
  "com.my.awesome.project.MyObject" = myobject
}
```

When I am running a single node I don't have any issues (obviously because I am not serializing anything...). However in cluster mode I keep getting these exceptions:

```
    2014-08-04 01:45:27,498 ERROR [MyApp-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16] - Slf4jLogger$$anonfun$receive$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply$mcV$sp (Slf4jLogger.scala:66) - Transient association error (association remains live)
    java.io.NotSerializableException: com.my.awesome.project.MyObject
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183) ~[?:1.7.0_60]
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547) ~[?:1.7.0_60]
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508) ~[?:1.7.0_60]
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431) ~[?:1.7.0_60]
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177) ~[?:1.7.0_60]
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347) ~[?:1.7.0_60]
            at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer$$anonfun$toBinary$1.apply$mcV$sp(Serializer.scala:129) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.4.jar:?]
            at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer$$anonfun$toBinary$1.apply(Serializer.scala:129) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.4.jar:?]
            at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer$$anonfun$toBinary$1.apply(Serializer.scala:129) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.4.jar:?]
            at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:?]
            at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer.toBinary(Serializer.scala:129) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.4.jar:?]
            at akka.remote.serialization.MessageContainerSerializer.serializeSelection(MessageContainerSerializer.scala:36) ~[akka-remote_2.11-2.3.4.jar:?]
            at akka.remote.serialization.MessageContainerSerializer.toBinary(MessageContainerSerializer.scala:25) ~[akka-remote_2.11-2.3.4.jar:?]
            at akka.remote.MessageSerializer$.serialize(MessageSerializer.scala:36) ~[akka-remote_2.11-2.3.4.jar:?]
            at akka.remote.EndpointWriter$$anonfun$serializeMessage$1.apply(Endpoint.scala:845) ~[akka-remote_2.11-2.3.4.jar:?]
            at akka.remote.EndpointWriter$$anonfun$serializeMessage$1.apply(Endpoint.scala:845) ~[akka-remote_2.11-2.3.4.jar:?]
            at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:?]
            at akka.remote.EndpointWriter.serializeMessage(Endpoint.scala:844) ~[akka-remote_2.11-2.3.4.jar:?]
            at akka.remote.EndpointWriter.writeSend(Endpoint.scala:747) ~[akka-remote_2.11-2.3.4.jar:?]
            at akka.remote.EndpointWriter$$anonfun$4.applyOrElse(Endpoint.scala:722) ~[akka-remote_2.11-2.3.4.jar:?]
            at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.4.jar:?]
            at akka.remote.EndpointActor.aroundReceive(Endpoint.scala:415) ~[akka-remote_2.11-2.3.4.jar:?]
            at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.4.jar:?]
            at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.4.jar:?]
            at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.4.jar:?]
            at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.4.jar:?]
            at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.4.jar:?]
            at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library-2.11.1.jar:?]
            at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library-2.11.1.jar:?]
            at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library-2.11.1.jar:?]
            at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library-2.11.1.jar:?]
```

And to me that means it is not able to figure out what serializer to use and it's actually using the generic Java one. Also, I don't know if it's related but I am wrapping my message with a ConsistentHashableEnvelope because I am sending it to a cluster-aware consistent hashing group.

Any help to make this thing work? Am I missing something?

Comment: Just as it is not clear from your pasted config, you do have serializers and serialization-bindings under akka.actor in your config, right?

Comment: Hi pushy, yes it is under akka.actor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Akka selects serializer once by message class (see stack trace). In your case akka correctly uses *JavaSerializer* because base message has ConsistentHashableEnvelope type and applies this serializer to all fields (*message* and *hashKey*).

To solve your task just create serlializer for *ConsistentHashableEnvelope* and use *MyObjectClusterSerializer* only if message field has *MyObject* type and *JavaSerializer* in other cases